# Bad layers in QGIS 3.4 after copying a template folder into a new project folder

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, layers, copy, data-source

I am working in QGIS 3.4.4. We have a template folder for all our QGIS maps. We then copy this folder into a new project folder and edit from there. One of the template maps uses a number of shapefiles from different sources. The template map will open as it should in QGIS from the original template folder and loads all the necessary shape files. However, when I make a copy of the template folder and paste this into a new project folder and try to open the same template map, the handle bad layers message returns. Could this have anything to do with the fact that I am using a VPN to work remotely from home and the projects and shapefiles are saved remotely on a drive? Let me know if there is any further information you need (I'm by no means a GIS expert).

Comment: it could come from a relative /absolute path setting could you check what setting the template has

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! Thanks so much. Something so simple :)